# Hyperledger Composer for Production Level Fabric Blockchain Business Solution

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a project in Hyperledger Fabric using Composer tools. I want to know whether Composer can be used for production level projects or not. If so, then **why one should develop their project in Fabric without Composer** as building a project in Composer is comparatively simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In production grade product you have:

- **Stability:** Composer  based on Hyperledger Fabric, so stability is equivalent to Hyperledger Fabric once it is up and running.
- **Security:** Hyperledger Fabric passed [a security audit](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/security/audits), something that **not done** for Hyperledger Composer.

Hyperledger Fabric has been deployed on production by [many companies around the world](https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/04/03/hyperledger-fabric-now-used-in-day-to-day-operations) also in [China](https://www.coindesk.com/huawei-unveils-hyperledger-based-blockchain-service-platform/) while google search for "hyperledger composer production" gives you a [post](https://discourse.skcript.com/t/is-hyperledger-composer-enterprise-production-ready/692) where it is says:

> the answer to the below question is NO
>
> Since the development of Composer is still in progress with the latest
>   version v0.18.0. The development team of Composer is very active and
>   the composer builds are deployed every week with some ‘Breaking
>   changes’. I would suggest keeping a track of the releases until
>   Version 1 of composer is released.

A [message](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/build-blockchain-prototype-minutes-hyperledger-olivier-kenji-mathurin) on LinkedIn says:

> I'd probably recommend to keep Hyperledger Composer for the
>   prototyping phase only, and then consider other options moving forward
>   based on how fast you plan to be in production

Comment: So the reason for not choosing Hyperledger Composer for production based project is that **no security audit** has been conducted on it and it is still is development phase?

Comment: Yes, because you never know if it has security bugs because no one officially tested it